# How to take binary string as an input and convert it to a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, input, binary

I want to take a binary string as an input (01110111) and convert the input to a list like this [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1] in Python. Can you help me how to do it?

TIA!

Comment: `l = list(map(int, '01110111'))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `list()` to split a word into a list of letters.

```
input = "01110111"
list_of_letters = list(input)
```